# Angular ng serve doesn't work

Tags: angular

Everytime i run ng serve it's give me that :

```
module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Projects\ng\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\src\tree\virtual.js:10:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

i installed nodejs stable version uninstall nodejs install another time but Nothing seems to work

Answer (score 2):

It's not **`ng server`**

it is

**`ng serve`**

Also,try the following manually

**`npm install @angular-devkit/core --save`**

Comment: soory i mean serve I tried this Doest work nether i have my old project who works fine btw

Comment: try installing globally npm install -g @angular-devkit/core

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just forgot to install or save to the `package.json` this package. Just run

```
npm i @angular-devkit/core --save
```

*"Angular ng server doesnt work"*

And the actual command to run Angular is `ng serve`, not `ng server`.

Comment: I tried this Doest work nether i have my old project who works fine btw

Comment: @Yoshi, you should run `ng serve` from the root of your projuct. Do you do it like this?

Comment: In window i do cd into the folder and run ng serve what is the root?:D

Comment: @Yoshi I mean the root folder of your project. If you will create new project with Angular CLI using `ng new PROJECT-NAME`, the `PROJECT-NAME` will be the root of your project.

Comment: So you installed using the angular cli?

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow, no, I'm trying to explain what I mean when say "the root of the project".

Comment: Sorry bad comment. I meant to confirm. @Yoshi did you install using the angular cli?

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json must see like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  }
```

If you create a new proyect, you will install the most recent major version (the first number) of these packages (e.g. @angular/animations@5.1.3 to @angular/animations@5.2.1 ). It's seems like some of these dependencies updates while you  create a new project. In my case, this work (from the older project):

```
+-- @angular/animations@5.1.3
| `-- tslib@1.8.1
+-- @angular/common@5.1.3
| `-- tslib@1.8.1 deduped
+-- @angular/compiler@5.1.3
| `-- tslib@1.8.1 deduped
+-- @angular/core@5.1.3
| `-- tslib@1.8.1 deduped
+-- @angular/forms@5.1.3

| `-- tslib@1.8.1 deduped
+-- @angular/http@5.1.3
| `-- tslib@1.8.1 deduped
+-- @angular/platform-browser@5.1.3
| `-- tslib@1.8.1 deduped
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.1.3
| `-- tslib@1.8.1 deduped
+-- @angular/router@5.1.3
| `-- tslib@1.8.1 deduped
+-- bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2
+-- core-js@2.5.3
+-- jquery@3.2.1
+-- popper.js@1.12.9
+-- rxjs@5.5.6
| `-- symbol-observable@1.0.1
`-- zone.js@0.8.19
```

And not this (new project):

```
+-- @angular/animations@5.2.1
| `-- tslib@1.9.0
+-- @angular/common@5.2.1
| `-- tslib@1.9.0 deduped
+-- @angular/compiler@5.2.1
| `-- tslib@1.9.0 deduped
+-- @angular/core@5.2.1
| `-- tslib@1.9.0 deduped
+-- @angular/forms@5.2.1

| `-- tslib@1.9.0 deduped
+-- @angular/http@5.2.1
| `-- tslib@1.9.0 deduped
+-- @angular/platform-browser@5.2.1
| `-- tslib@1.9.0 deduped
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.2.1
| `-- tslib@1.9.0 deduped
+-- @angular/router@5.2.1
| `-- tslib@1.9.0 deduped
+-- core-js@2.5.3
+-- rxjs@5.5.6
| `-- symbol-observable@1.0.1
`-- zone.js@0.8.20
```

I resolved this problem updating angular cli to the latest version (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli) and doing a
`npm install` or `npm install --save` if your npm version is < 5.0.0.
This will update the dev-dependencies in your package.json and node_modules.